# D7: Blog post set to language but all the time visible

Tags: i18n-l10n, nodes

I created to blog post, one in english, on in german.
But if I launch set a menu link with the link "http://www.drupalsite.com/en/blog", I still see all blog posts.

How to change that it only display posts in the defined language?

Thanks